# Can "AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess" policy be used to list all buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

`AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess` policy is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

So adding this to a particular `role` should allow the `users` who assume that `role` to be able to view their buckets from AWS management console? (as the action `List*` matches `ListAllMyBuckets` action)?

[image]

But the users are not able to view their buckets.

Where am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How are the users assuming the role in the console?

Answer (score 0):

The policy looks fine to me. You should make sure that the user is actually using the said role on the console. (Being able to assume a role and actually doing it are two different things)

Alternatively, instead of attaching the policy to *a specific role* you could consider attaching the policy to the user itself

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are fine, but your users must **manually** [assume the role in the console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html):

[image]